# SQL query, group by and number of occurrences

Tags: query

I have the following table (only one column):

```
X
----
1
1
1
2
2
3
3
3
4
4
5
6
6
7
7
7
```

I need a SQL query which will output the following:

```
Occurrences | Number
1  1  * there are only 1 entry with one occurrence (number 5)
2  3  * there are three entries with two occurrences (numbers 2,4,6)
3  2  * there are two entries with three occurrences (numbers 1 and 7)
```

If I do something like this:

```
select count(*) FROM (SELECT count(*) as N FROM table 1 GROUP BY x) a GROUP BY a.N;
```

I get the correct results, but only the second column t with the number of occurrences. 
Does anyone know how to get the complete output as in the example above?

Comment: Which DBMS is this for? (Postgres, SQL Server, DB2, SQLite, MySQL, Oracle, ...) There are tens and the solution may differ.

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like you're trying to dumb down the real question.  What possible use is a table with a single column?  If this is not the real question you need answered, please edit your question to show the actual real-world question.  Add `CREATE TABLE` statements, with `INSERT INTO ...` statements for the data, along with expected output in table form.  Check [these details](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example) for an example.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
select count(*), a.N FROM (SELECT count(*) as N FROM table1 GROUP BY x) a GROUP BY a.N;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8b19a/1)

Note that it gives you **3** for N = 3, because there are actually three number repeated thrice: 1, 3 and 7.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the query you might need:

```
select t.count as Occurrences, count(*) as Number from
(select a, count(*) as count from table_1 group by a)t 
group by t.count 
order by Occurrences;
```